# Is it possible to create helium atoms by bombarding heavy water with neutrons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, water, neutrons, nucleosynthesis

If heavy water is bombarded by neutrons is it possible that any of the deuterium atoms can capture neutrons and transmute to helium atoms?

I suspect the more probable event would be knocking protons out of the deuterium and creating simple hydrogen, but curious if the other reaction might ever be possible.

What products can one expect with different neutron energies?

Comment: Best i can think of is that you wont create helium since that requires extra protons not neutrons, maybe a small chance to form tritium instead which is heavier hydrogen (1proton, 2neutron). The wikipedia article discusses tritium forming from heavy water bombardment, which is sort of similar http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deuterium reacts with low energy neutrons to form tritium, though the cross section is very low. Tritium beta decays to $^3$He with a half life of about 12 years, so the process results in very slow production of $^3$He. The trouble is that $^3$He also reacts with low energy neutrons, but it forms tritium and a free proton rather than $^4$He.

So the deuteron-neutron reaction isn't a practical way to make helium.